# Not able to see scroll in mobile and tablet

Tags: html, css, mobile, scroll, tablet

Using the following code, I'm not able to see the scroll-bar in mobile and tablet. I'm able to see the scroll if using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> in Firefox, but when viewing on a mobile I am not able to see the scroll. What should I do to get the scroll bar in mobile and tablet.(I'm able to scroll, not seeing scroll bar)

The `html`:

```
<div class="myScroll">
   <p>asdf ;lkj asdf ;lkj asdf ;lkj asdf ;lkj </p>
   <p>asdf ;lkj asdf ;lkj asdf ;lkj asdf ;lkj </p>
   <p>asdf ;lkj asdf ;lkj asdf ;lkj asdf ;lkj </p>
   <p>asdf ;lkj asdf ;lkj asdf ;lkj asdf ;lkj </p>
   <p>asdf ;lkj asdf ;lkj asdf ;lkj asdf ;lkj </p>
   <p>asdf ;lkj asdf ;lkj asdf ;lkj asdf ;lkj </p>
   <p>asdf ;lkj asdf ;lkj asdf ;lkj asdf ;lkj </p>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.myScroll{
   display:inline-block;
   height:100px;
   overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you don't see a scroll *bar* or you *can't scroll* period?

Comment: I can scroll, but cant see the scroll bar :)

Comment: Did you try to use some other browser? or phone? Many times it depends on the browser.

Comment: I'm able to see the scroll bar in chrome using some re-sizer.I have got this issue on ipad and iphone.